# Problems with string and accents PHP

Tags: php, string

I have problems with strings similar to these that have accents In the Initial Word.

for example : (nesecito grabs the first letter of each word of that name.)

```
$string =  'Álvaro Álvarez';
$parts = explode(" ", $string);
foreach($parts as $part){
    echo $part[0].'<br>';
}
```

I have this result for each letter:
�
�

if i use utf8_encode i have this as a result for each letter :
Ã
Ã
but those are not the letters, the letters are Á Á

Here is an example of what I did.

[example online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fa24a23ae16554d321063f035837488009d76124)

The result I'm looking for is Á Á
If someone can help me solve this dilemma, I will be grateful.

Comment: In your example, You `echo` the `$part[0]` two times. So it gives this kind of results. Just remove the first echo.

Comment: So the issue with characters like `Á` is that they are multi-byte. Accessing PHP string characters via index assumes single-byte characters so you're only getting half of each character. As a test, try `echo substr($part, 0, 2)` instead :)

Comment: ... but please don't do that in production. Use `mb_substr()` as mentioned in the linked duplicate

Comment: thanks Phil!! ,Thanks for taking the time and for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your HTML header

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
```

If it didn't solve your problem try adding this at the beginning of your php file

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```

Comment: Good advice in general for HTML unicode output but not the issue here